# Using dat.gui sliders to rotate bones from Blender json / collada in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, dat.gui

I want to know how to manipulate the bones of a json / collada file exported from Blender. Been trying to do this for a while to no avail.

I want to be able to use sliders (through dat.gui) to rotate each bone

Can anyone point me in the right direction or help?

I want to end up with a human model, where i can manipulate each bone / limb with the dat.gui sliders

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [Dat.GUI docs](http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#2--Constraining-Input), you should create the gui like this:

```js
var gui = new dat.GUI();
document.body.appendChild( gui.domElement );

function addBoneSliders(bone) {
  var folder = gui.addFolder( bone.name );

  folder.add( bone.rotation, 'x' );
  folder.add( bone.rotation, 'y' );
  folder.add( bone.rotation, 'z' );
}
```

and, in your loader callback

```js
collada.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {
  if ( child instanceof THREE.Bone ) {
    addBoneSliders( child );
  }
});
```

I haven't tested it but it should work.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.

Could you show me how this might work?
I can't seem to implement it into my own code without errors or a white screen.

Thanks again

Comment: @vincent if the bone is named leg.L and leg.R, how to address them in the bone.name?

Comment: @JuneWang not sure to understand. if the collada object you get has a name attribute, then you just have to check this in the test statement (and add both legs sliders)